# Django REST Framework ParseError when accessing request.DATA

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How should I structure a function-based view to return an HTTP 400 when a client submits a request with invalid JSON?

The REST Framework [Request documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests#parsers) states that a `ParseError` may be raised when accessing `request.DATA` that contains invalid JSON. The documentation goes on to state that if the view function has been decorated using `@api_view`, the error will be caught and an HTTP  400 Bad Request will be returned to the client.

In the views that I create, when I access `request.DATA` I receive an HTTP 500 `ParseError` rather than the expected HTTP 400.

My view is structured like this:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

from serializers import PersonSerializer

@api_view(['POST'])
def person_list(request):

    # Deserialize the incoming JSON into a Person object.
    # FIXME: ParseError raised here if JSON is invalid!
    person = PersonSerializer(data=request.DATA)

    # Ensure that the request contains valid data.
    if not person.is_valid():
        return Response(person.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    # Save the Person object into the Mongo backend.
    person.save()

    return Response(person.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

My serializer is structured like this:

```
  from rest_framework import serializers

  class PersonSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
      name = serializers.CharField()
      surname = serializers.CharField()
      age = serializers.IntegerField()

      def restore_object(self, attrs, instance):
          """Given a dictionary of deserialized field values or create a new
          model instance.
          """
          return Event(**attrs)
```

Note that I'm not using a ModelSerializer as the model is provided by [mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/) not the Django ORM.

If I send an invalid JSON string to the view (for example, POSTing without any content) or using this string: `{"name": "Alice", "surname" "Test", "age": 30}` (note the missing colon `:` after `"surname"`) Django will return an HTTP 500 with:

```
ParseError at /people/
No exception message supplied
```

Even if I try and access `request.DATA` without passing it to the `PersonSerializer` the `ParseError` is raised.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this.

I ran this code:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['POST'])
def person_list(request):

    data = request.DATA
    print data

    return Response({}, status=200)

from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from django.test.utils import override_settings

class TestFoo(APITestCase):
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
    urls = patterns('',
        url(r'^test$', person_list),
    )

    @override_settings(APPEND_SLASH=False)
    def test_thing(self):
        bad_json = '{"name": "Alice", "surname" "Test", "age": 30}'
        resp = self.client.post('/test', bad_json, content_type='application/json')
        print resp.status_code
        print resp
```

and got this output:

```
400
Vary: Accept, Cookie
Content-Type: application/json
Allow: POST, OPTIONS

{"detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 29 (char 28)"}
```

Which version of rest_framework are you using? Can you provide some code which includes a failing test? Is there something in your settings.REST_FRAMEWORK which might be affecting this?